# Python2 And Python3

Tags: python, syntax-error, findall, python-re

This is for Python 2:

```
import re

print sum([int(i) for i in re.findall('[0-9]+',open(raw_input('What is the file you want to analyze?\n'),'r').read())])
```

But why do I get a syntax error with Python 3?

Python3

```
import re

print sum([int(i) for i in re.findall('[0-9]+',open(input('What is the file you want to analyze?\n')).read())])
```

Comment: `print()` is a function in Python 3. Also, this whole piece of code is just a piece of ugliness - I hope that was just for fun...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because in Python3 you should use brackets around the argument for the print function.

print()

so your code will work as soon as you write

print(sum([int(i) for i in re.findall('[0-9]+',open(input('What is the file you want to analyze?\n')).read())]))